# Creating Unique Identifier in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, uniqueidentifier

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a GUID / UUID in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript)

I have a need to create a unique identifier in JavaScript.  I don't care what it is as long as it is unique across all computers in the world.  I thought of somehow concatenating the unique ID (mac address?) of a PC with a date/time stamp but don't know how to do this.  Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to get a mac address from a browser (javascript) and it's tricky - (but not impossible) on the server. It's also not guaranteed to be unique in the world - I've heard of large organizations who had collisions inside their corporate networks.